# Persistence of Value After Message Cycle

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

In the message life cycle there are flow vars, scoped to a flow or sub-flow, and session vars, that are scoped to the transaction but end with the message cycle. I need to keep a value across messages. What is the correct way to save a value across messages?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to implement objectstore

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mule-object-stores